# For $1\leq a\leq p-1$ and $5\leq p$, show that $\sum_{(a/p)=1}^{} a \equiv 0 \pmod{p}$

Tags: number-theory

> For $1\leq a\leq p-1$ and $5\leq p$, show that $$\sum_{(a/p)=1} a \equiv 0 \pmod{p}$$ where $(a/p)$ is the Legende symbol.

I know that there are as many quadratic residues as quadratic nonresidues, but I have no idea of how they are distributed.

Hints or complete solutions would be appreciated.

Comment: Hint: If $r$ is a primitive root of $p$ then the quadratic residues are congruent mod $p$ to the even powers of $r$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Note that, quadratic residues are precisely members of the set, $\{1^2,2^2,\dots,\left(\frac{p-1}{2}\right)^2\}$, where I assume the rest of the arithmetic to be done modulo $p$.

Now, 
$$
\sum_{k=1}^{\frac{p-1}{2}}k^2 \equiv \frac{\frac{p-1}{2}\cdot \frac{p+1}{2}p}{6} \pmod{p}.
$$
Since $p\neq 2,3$, the result follows immediately.